# jupyter notebookでTabキーを押したらスペース4つではなくtabが出るようになる方法を教えてください

Tags: jupyter-notebook

jupyter notebookでタブキーを押したら、自分の環境ではスペース4つに置き換わるんですが、これをtabが出るように変えるにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか。

`jupyter notebook インデント タブに変更`などで検索しても出なかったので質問します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jupyter notebookでは不可能ですが、後継であるJupyterlabでは可能なようです。
[Using tabs in Jupyter notebook cells · Issue #10423 · ipython/ipython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10423)
[Using tabs in Jupyter notebook cells (re-open #10423) · Issue #10994 · ipython/ipython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10994)

> jupyterlab allows you to choose whether indent is done with space or tab.